# Recharts: Can't fix height of LineChart with custom Legend in ResponsiveContainer

Tags: css, reactjs, recharts

I'm trying to fix Chart's height value but with responsive container it move in dependency with customLegend. So result is when Legend has got few elements (low height value) LineChart become bigger and vice versa. Many elements in Legend => small LineChart height

```js
<div
      style={{
        width: "100%",
        paddingBottom: 30,
        maxHeight: 1200
      }}
    >
      <ResponsiveContainer width={"100%"} minHeight={650} >
        <LineChart height={300}
          data={DataSet}
          margin={{  right: 30}}
        >
          <CartesianGrid strokeDasharray="3 3" />
          <XAxis dataKey="sold" />
          <YAxis />

          <Tooltip wrapperStyle={{ fontSize: 12 }} />
          <Point..../>
          <Brush height={25} />
          <Legend chartHeight={300}
            content={renderLegend}
            wrapperStyle={{ paddingTop: 20 }}
            align={"left"}
          />
        </LineChart>
      </ResponsiveContainer>
</div>
```

So I tried to put fixed height everywhere as documented in API, but it didn't work. Without height param chart not displayed at all. What's wrong with my CSS?

v1.8.5